# Setting Docker on Jenkins server

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on upgrading our freestyle Jenkins projects to the pipelines.  I also want to use Docker to package our applications. I have installed the cloudbees Docker build and publish plugin. I have installed Docker on the Jenkins server as well. Added the Jenkins user to the docker group. When I log in to the Jenkins server and go to the workspace I can run docker commands without any error and image is built but in Jenkinsfile I get the following error.

```
    [eline_jenkins-pipeline-test-
    PBD3XJTE26LKZXM5M45IPRS3DXQANE4R2Q6GCDSZAPOHBNXKQDQQ] Running shell 
    script
    + docker build -t test-image .
    Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon 
    socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post 
    http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.32/build?
    dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

My Jenkinsfile is as follows:

```
   stage('Build Docker Container') {
        steps {
                script{
                       def app = docker.build "my-app:0.2"
                }                   
        }
    }
```

In the past, I have worked with Jenkins and docker but at that time I was using Jenkins as a container, in this situation it is not possible to move to the containerized Jenkins.  Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The user running the build almost certainly does not have access to the Docker socket. If in your `Jenkinsfile` you run `sh 'id'` what is the output?

Comment: I ran whoami in the Jenkinsfile and the output was Jenkins and jenkins user has been added to docker group.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by changing the permission of the /var/run/dock.sock file to 666. Its default permission is 660 and I don't understand why Jenkins user that is in the docker group can't access this file when executing the pipeline job but it can on the commandline directly.  This is a workaround and it worked for me. I hope this will help someone else as well.